# Failed to append data in .json file using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs, readfile

I want to append my  data which is array of object format to the existing .json file so I have written code for it, but on stackoverflow I noticed so many developers suggesting before appending to existing json file first read file and then push new data to existing json file. So I followed this and made changes according to this but getting error :

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
```

Code written in node

```
 newdata=[
  {
    UserId: '11',
    UserName: 'harry',
   
  },
  {
    UserId: 12,
    UserName: 'David',
  }
];

     fs.readFile('results.json', function (err, data) {
    if(data === '') {
        json = JSON.parse(newdata);
        json.push(newdata);
    }
    fs.writeFile("results.json", JSON.stringify(json));
  })
```

Comment: `fs.writeFile` needs as third/last option a  function/callback: RTFM: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because you are using the *.writeFile* in a wrong way.

Try something like this:

```
fs.writeFile('results.json', JSON.stringify(newData), function(err) {
    if (err) throw err; 
});
```

A short explanation:

The *ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK* in the error message is the missing of the function informed in the last parameter in the example above.

```
fs.writeFile(<file>, <content>, <callback>)
```